# Binding imgui library in conan package manager

Tags: c++, conan, premake, imgui

Hey i follow tutorial about imGUI but i have a problem with libraries binding.
Here`s a reference to tutorial: https://youtu.be/U1BnzWX194Q?t=1419 .

This is how my premake5.lua file looks like

```lua
-- Include conan gennerate script
include("conanbuildinfo.premake.lua")

-- Main Workspace
workspace "GameOfLife"
    -- Import conan gennerate config
    conan_basic_setup()

    -- Project
    project "GOL"
        kind "ConsoleApp"
        language "C++"
        targetdir "bin/%{cfg.buildcfg}"
        objdir "bin/%{cfg.buildcfg}/obj/"
        location "src"
        debugdir "app"

        linkoptions { conan_exelinkflags }

        files { "**.hpp", "**.cpp" }

        filter "configurations:Debug"
        defines { "DEBUG" }
        symbols "On"

        filter "configurations:Release"
        defines { "NDEBUG" }
        optimize "On"
```

and conanfile.txt

```
[requires]
imgui/1.89.1
glfw/3.3.8
glad/0.1.36

[generators]
premake

[options]
*:shared=True

[imports]
bin,*.dll -> ./app
```

I looked in internet but i cant find any reference about it.

Comment: I suggest submitting a ticket to https://github.com/conan-io/conan, also including the failure, i.e. the whole commands used and the whole output, including the error messages. Also, what other configurations work or don't work, for example, does it work if linking statically, not using ``shared=True``?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to add binding

1. I created bindings folder
2. To premake5.lua i added this folder
   liked this:

   `includedirs { "./bindings" }`
3. In conanfile.txt i added imports like:

   ```
    [imports]
    ./res/bindings, imgui_impl_glfw.h -> ./bindings
    ./res/bindings, imgui_impl_opengl3.h -> ./bindings
    ./res/bindings, imgui_impl_opengl3_loader.h -> ./bindings
   ```

I dont know it is good aproach but vs code see those bindings

Edit: So far it work with shared and static options